# Executing PHP function from JSON

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying some things with JSON and PHP and there is something that I can't find a way to do, though I'm not 100% sure there is one. But because it looks like a nice option (If possible) I decided to ask here.

I have these examples from jquery offical site. There are two files, the first one is index.php where I execute my Ajax, hete it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple form sending and receiving a JSON object to/from PHP</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var data = 
  { 
    "sales": [ 
      { "firstname" : "John", "lastname" : "Brown" },
      { "firstname" : "Marc", "lastname" : "Johnson" }
    ] // end of sales array
  }
  var dataString = JSON.stringify(data);
  $.post('simpleformSubmi.php', { data: dataString}, showResult, "text");
});

function showResult(res)
{
  $("#fullresponse").html("Full response: " +res);
}
</script>
<div id="fullresponse"></div>
</head>
<body>
```

Nothing complicated at all. And I have my simpleformSubmi.php which is :

```
<?php

$logFile = 'logFile';
$res = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']), true);
error_log("result: ".$_POST['data'].", res=".json_encode($res), 3, $logFile);
error_log("\n", 3, $logFile);

//header("Content-type: text/plain");
foreach ($res as $key=>$value)
{
    $str[] = $value;
}
$functionArray ="function(){ \$a = 10; echo \$a;}";
$jsStr = $str[0][1];
echo json_encode($jsStr['firstname']);
echo '<hr />';
echo json_encode($res);
echo '<hr />';
echo json_encode($functionArray);
?>
```

As you can see $functionArray - is in fact a string containing PHP function which I want to return back using JSON and to execute it after that. So is there any way to do that really? Now what I get in index.php afet executing the files is:

`"function(){ $a = 10; echo $a;}`"

Thanks
Lern

Comment: you can't get JSON to execute anything PHP...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to execute a PHP function through JavaScript. Since PHP is executed server-side the only way you have to execute a PHP function in that context is to ask the server back to execute the function for you, by doing another ajax call for example.

Something like this:

index.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var data = 
  { 
    "sales": [ 
      { "firstname" : "John", "lastname" : "Brown" },
      { "firstname" : "Marc", "lastname" : "Johnson" }
    ] // end of sales array
  }
  var dataString = JSON.stringify(data);

  //Change post() success callback function to executePHP()
  $.post('simpleformSubmi.php', { data: dataString}, executePHP, "text");

  //Let's define executePHP() outside post() call for clarity
  function executePHP()
  {
      //Ask the server to execute function foo(), and get the result
      $.get("example.com/somefile.php?function=foo", function(data)
      {
          //Success function, do whatever you want.
          alert(data);
      });
  }
});
```

Then, in somefile.php

```
<?php
//Condition(s), if any. You could even implement this interface using REST.
//Get function to execute
if($_GET["function"] == "foo")
{
    //Output function's result.
    echo foo();
}

//The function you want to run
function foo()
{
    //Do something
    $a = 10;
    return $a;
}
?>
```

If all went well, when JavaScript reaches the `alert(data);` statement you will see `10`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute a PHP function after sending it as a response since the response is received on the client end, and PHP is a server side language.

Usually, you would just return the values. In your example, you would just return an associative array that holds the key value pair `a,10`.

You can return javascript functions from the PHP script and execute that on the client side using `eval` but `eval'ing` opens a pandora's box of security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Yeah, reading your comment makes me feel a little stupid right now. Obv. there's no way to execute PHP script on the client side, but the second part about the JS functions and eval seems interesting to me.

Comment: Read up about the hazards of `eval` carefully and how to use it securely.

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute PHP code outside of a PHP server. So you can't run it in the browser.

You can, however, pass a string of JavaScript and run it through `eval`. Some people will tell you that's bad, but remember that `eval` used to be the only way to parse JSON in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In order to send back something to PHP, you must call the serverside via, p.e via GET or POST actions from a form. But, no, you cannot execute anything serverside via echo, as echo outputs to the client side. You could always use eval (http://php.net/manual/es/function.eval.php) at serverside to execute something from a POST message, but it is not recommended as it can open a great security hole.

Answer (score 0):

You've returned a function (I'm assuming you meant this to be javascript), now you need to call it. This can be done by using the jQuery $.post success callback.

Try changing this..

```
$.post('simpleformSubmi.php', { data: dataString}, showResult, "text");
```

To

```
$.post('simpleformSubmi.php', { data: dataString}, function(data){eval(data)}, "text");
```

If its PHP (which it looks like) and not Javascript, then this will need to executed from the server. Being that its a server-side language 'n all.