# How to call a PHP function within a $.getJSON function?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, getjson

A PHP function should return a specific number and stored it to the variable data[i]. How to access a PHP function within a $.getJSON function? I used a PHP CodeIgniter framework. Thank you!

```
`$.getJSON("<?php echo site_url('some_contoller/some_funcion');?>", function (data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var data[i] = "<?php echo $this->some_PHP_function($with_parameter)?>";
  }
```

}`

This is my PHP function:

```
public function get_report_pictures($report_id) {
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->where('report_id', $report_id);
  $query = $this->db->get('report');
  $data = $query->result();

  return $data;
```

}

Comment: Hello. You can't directly access PHP <-> Javascript. PHP runs on server, Javascript on browser. For interaction between both, use AJAX.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you! So i'll use AJAX to call a PHP function then?

Comment: could you post your controller's function.

Comment: I think this stack answer will get some help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904272/executing-php-function-from-json

Answer (score 0):

in javascript file (*.js) you can't use php code.

you can use $.ajax() to call function in controller .

```
   $.ajax({
           type: "post",
           url: "some_contoller/some_funcion",         
           dataType :'json',
           success: function(response){
               if(response.status=='success'){
                response.data.forEach( function (item)
                 {
                  var x = item.number;
                   console.log(x);
                 });
                }
           },error:function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               console.log(textStatus);
              }
         });
```

in function you mentioned 'some_funcion'

```
echo  json_encode(array(
                        'status'=>'failed',
                        'data'   => 'number you say ') 
                       );
             exit();
```

it's my solution.i hope so that's worked.